# clang-tidy isolate multiple field declarations

Tags: c++, clang-tidy, clang-query

In clang-tidy there is the readability-isolate-declaration check.
I am trying to do something similar for field declarations.

Let us say that we have the following

```
typedef struct s{
    int x,y;
}s;
```

If we check the above example in clang-query we get something like

```
CXXRecordDecl 0x555e28564740 <<source>:1:9, line:4:1> line:1:16 struct s definition

|-DefinitionData pass_in_registers aggregate standard_layout trivially_copyable pod trivial literal

| |-DefaultConstructor exists trivial needs_implicit

| |-CopyConstructor simple trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param

| |-MoveConstructor exists simple trivial needs_implicit

| |-CopyAssignment trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param

| |-MoveAssignment exists simple trivial needs_implicit

| `-Destructor simple irrelevant trivial needs_implicit

|-CXXRecordDecl 0x555e28564858 <col:9, col:16> col:16 implicit struct s

|-FieldDecl 0x555e28564900 <line:2:5, col:9> col:9 x 'int'

 -FieldDecl 0x555e28564968 <col:5, col:11> col:11 y 'int'
```

Here I get 2 different FieldDecls for x and y. I also get 2 FieldDecls in the following case

```
typedef struct s{
    int x;
    int y;
}s;
```

```
CXXRecordDecl 0x5648bcf47740 <<source>:1:9, line:5:1> line:1:16 struct s definition

|-DefinitionData pass_in_registers aggregate standard_layout trivially_copyable pod trivial literal

| |-DefaultConstructor exists trivial needs_implicit

| |-CopyConstructor simple trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param

| |-MoveConstructor exists simple trivial needs_implicit

| |-CopyAssignment trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param

| |-MoveAssignment exists simple trivial needs_implicit

| `-Destructor simple irrelevant trivial needs_implicit

|-CXXRecordDecl 0x5648bcf47858 <col:9, col:16> col:16 implicit struct s

|-FieldDecl 0x5648bcf47900 <line:2:5, col:9> col:9 x 'int'

`-FieldDecl 0x5648bcf47968 <line:3:5, col:9> col:9 y 'int'
```

This is nearly identical.
How can someone distinguish between the two cases based on the AST?

Comment: OT: Why use `typedef struct` in C++?

Comment: @underscore_d this is an example for practice in clang-tidy. Also, typedef struct may appear in c++ code so it is safer to have it in your tool than ignoring it.